# Xamarin Forms Grid Row & Columns Definitions

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.forms, grid

Hola tengo el este `ContentPage`

[image: X]

lo que necesito es que a la segunda row tome el `width` completo y la 1 y 3 era row se queden con las definiciones que estan ahora para que la segunda row me quede toda en verde, alguien sabe como hacerlo? como no le agarro al **Grid**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"

             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Miapp.MainPage">
    <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,0">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*" x:Name="firstRow" />
                <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />


            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <StackLayout 
                Padding="5,0,5,0"
                x:Name="s1"  
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=s1}"  >

                <Label x:Name="Msn" />
                <Image
                    Source="iko.png"
                    x:Name="ImgProfile">
                </Image>
                <Label x:Name="UserNamelb" Text="Nombre de usuario" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="s2" BackgroundColor="#128C7E" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=s2}">
                <Button Text="Lavado al instante"  BackgroundColor="#075E54"  TextColor="Accent" 
                        Clicked="Lavadobtn_Clicked"
                        x:Name="Lavadobtn" />
                <Button Text="Direccion" BackgroundColor="#075E54"  TextColor="Accent" 
                        x:Name="Direccionbtn"
                        Clicked="Direccionbtn_Clicked"
                        />
                <Button Text="Agregar auto" BackgroundColor="#075E54"  TextColor="Accent" 
                        x:Name="AddCarbtn"
                        Clicked="AddCarbtn_Clicked"
                        />
                <Button Text="Registro"  BackgroundColor="#075E54" TextColor="Accent"
                        x:Name="Registbtn"
                        Clicked="Registbtn_Clicked"
                        />

                <Button Text="Agendar fecha"  BackgroundColor="#075E54"  TextColor="Accent"
                        x:Name="Agendarbtn"
                        Clicked="Agendarbtn_Clicked"
                        />

            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout x:Name="s3" BackgroundColor="Accent" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="0"  BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=s3}">
                <Label Text="  Aqui va mapa  " Grid.ColumnSpan="1"  TextColor="Black"/>
            </StackLayout>



            <StackLayout x:Name="s5" BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=s5}">
                <Label Text="    "  TextColor="Accent"/>
                <Label Text="   " />
                <Label Text="   " />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout x:Name="s6" BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=s6}">

            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: ¿Estás haciendo algún curso de Xamarin?

Comment: @fredyfx no , estoy aprendiendo sobre la marcha, no es que no quiera no tengo tiempo , prefiero leer en internet , probar , preguntar

Comment: Para cuando decidas hacer espacio/tiempo https://Microsoft.com/learn ahí se encuentra gratis el material de Xamarin University que en su tiempo costaba 2000$ USD al año.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize Grid.ColumnSpan={número de columnas}. Veo que tiene 2 columnas definidas así que solo pasele el Grid.ColumnSpan=2 al control que quiere que ocupe todo el ancho.

A continuación el código:

```
<StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,0">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" x:Name="firstRow" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />


        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <StackLayout 
            Padding="5,0,5,0"
            x:Name="s1"  
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
            BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=s1}"  >

            <Label x:Name="Msn" />
            <Image
                Source="iko.png"
                x:Name="ImgProfile">
            </Image>
            <Label x:Name="UserNamelb" Text="Nombre de usuario" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="s2" BackgroundColor="#128C7E" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=s2}">
            <Button Text="Lavado al instante"  BackgroundColor="#075E54"  TextColor="Accent" 
                    Clicked="Lavadobtn_Clicked"
                    x:Name="Lavadobtn" />
            <Button Text="Direccion" BackgroundColor="#075E54"  TextColor="Accent" 
                    x:Name="Direccionbtn"
                    Clicked="Direccionbtn_Clicked"
                    />
            <Button Text="Agregar auto" BackgroundColor="#075E54"  TextColor="Accent" 
                    x:Name="AddCarbtn"
                    Clicked="AddCarbtn_Clicked"
                    />
            <Button Text="Registro"  BackgroundColor="#075E54" TextColor="Accent"
                    x:Name="Registbtn"
                    Clicked="Registbtn_Clicked"
                    />

            <Button Text="Agendar fecha"  BackgroundColor="#075E54"  TextColor="Accent"
                    x:Name="Agendarbtn"
                    Clicked="Agendarbtn_Clicked"
                    />

        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout x:Name="s3" 
                     BackgroundColor="Accent" 
                     Grid.Row="1"  
                     Grid.Column="0"  
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                     BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=s3}">
            <Label Text="  Aqui va mapa  " Grid.ColumnSpan="1"  TextColor="Black"/>
        </StackLayout>



        <StackLayout x:Name="s5" BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=s5}">
            <Label Text="    "  TextColor="Accent"/>
            <Label Text="   " />
            <Label Text="   " />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout x:Name="s6" BackgroundColor="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=s6}">

        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Podrias agregar a tu respuesta como lo harías, necesito que el `StackLayout x:Name="s3" ` sea quien ocupe todo el ancho

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim  Intente con esa modificación que hice. Si le funciona favor marcar la pregunta como resuelta.